# Javascript - searching object by key

Tags: javascript, json, search, loops, optimization

I know there's plenty of answers on this and most are suggesting looping thru the object, returning what you need, I'm not sure this is the best approach, in my case anyway.

What I have is array with `entries` referencing to another array `people`(with `id` and `name`) by `person_id` and `projects`(with `id` and `name`) by `project_id`.

What I need is to be able to access project and person with a particular `id` inside the loop on `entries`, so I can get their names. Doing what others have suggested I'd loop thru `people` and `projects` inside each irritation of `entries`, which seems like awful lot of looping.

So I thought I'd make something I called a "hashtable" from both `people` and `projects` on init, which means pretty much creating a new objects `people_hashtable` and `projects_hashtable` where key would be the id

so

```
[
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "John Doe"
  }
]
```

would became

```
{
    "8": {
        "name": "John Doe"
    }
}
```

this way I'd have easy access to the name without looping all the time while still maintaining the old array with its original order(that's why I'm not outputting it this way directly from server, you can't quite order an object and I'm using both `people` and `projects` in a selectbox, which needs to be ordered by name).

Am I doing it right? Are there better way? Or should I forget this completely and stick with the search loop as suggested in other question?

I'm trying to be as efficient as possible on both server and client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically doubled all the objects just to avoid loop. So, unless you have some bad performance issues, I would avoid that.
In case you really, really need a kind of hashmap, I would prefer storing the array's index instead of another copy of the object:

```
// array
var arr = [
  {
    "id": "8",
     "name": "John Doe"
  }
];

// lookup table
var lookup = {
  "8": 0
}
```

Of course doing that, means you can't modifying the array's without rebuild the hashmap.

Generate it's quite simple:

```
var lookup = arr.reduce(function(lookup, item, index) {
  lookup[item.id] = index;
  return lookup;
}, {});
```

You can also use that to generate the object you mentioned your question:

```
var lookup = arr.reduce(function(lookup, item) {
  lookup[item.id] = {name: item.name};
  return lookup;
}, {});
```

But as I said it's something I would avoid.

Comment: That's interesting! Yeah I suppose that's better than copying the whole object.

Comment: reduce seems to be ecma5 stuff though, so I might have to stick to the good old for to build the lookup table

Comment: ES5 is supported in all major and modern browsers; plus ES6 is on the way. If you have to support old browsers like IE8, then I suggest to use always a [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim). Specifically only for `reduce` can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0):

Following code may help you. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KrnYT/)

```
var arr = [
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "John Doe"
  }
];

var obj = {};
for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
   obj[arr[i].id] = {name: arr[i].name};
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I know how to do this, I was rather asking for whether it's a good idea. The question was probably lost in the wall of text. Sorry.

Comment: Definitely, this is good idea as it make seach fast and easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
var articles= {
    "item1":{
         "id":"155",
         "name":"First Item",
         "value":-5199.6
    },
    "item2":{
         "id":"255",
         "name":"Second Item",
         "value":-424.91
    }
}

var ids = [];
for(var item in articles) {
    ids.push(articles[item]['id']);
}

console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score -1):

This lib https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr makes it pretty easy to do. Both normalization and denormalization.

It can turn this

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "author": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Paul"
  },
  "title": "My awesome blog post",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": "324",
      "commenter": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nicole"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

into this

```
{
  result: "123",
  entities: {
    "articles": { 
      "123": { 
        id: "123",
        author: "1",
        title: "My awesome blog post",
        comments: [ "324" ]
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "1": { "id": "1", "name": "Paul" },
      "2": { "id": "2", "name": "Nicole" }
    },
    "comments": {
      "324": { id: "324", "commenter": "2" }
    }
  }
}
```

and the other way around.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16462894)

Comment: It does not make much sense, in this case anyway. Considering the answer is pointing to a library, I would need to keep the snippet in my answer always up to date with the API of said library (which did change completely recently), while it's obviously always up to date on the project's github. I did add an example of the library does with the data, which is exactly what I asked for in the question, so it doesn't make much sense either, but whatever.